# Why is a `lambdef` allowed as a type-hint for variables?

Tags: python, python-3.x, grammar

The Python [grammar](https://docs.python.org/3.11/reference/grammar.html) has this rule:

```
assignment:
    | NAME ':' expression ['=' annotated_rhs ] 
    # other options for rule omitted
```

while the `expression` rules permit a lambda definition (`lambdef`).

That means this python syntax is valid:

```py
q: lambda p: p * 4 = 1
```

Is there a use case for permitting a lambda there, or is this just a quirk of a somewhat loose grammar? Similarly, this allows conditional types `a: int if b > 3 else str = quux`, which seems a bit more sane but still unexpected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is specified under the [PEP-0526(Syntax for Variable Annotations)](https://peps.python.org/pep-0526/#other-uses-of-annotations). Python does not care about the annotation as long as **“it evaluates without raising”**. It's the duty of the type-checker to flag it as invalid annotation.

Quoting from the PEP:

> **Other uses of annotations**
>
> While Python with this PEP will not object
> to:
>
> `alice: 'well done' = 'A+'`
>
> `bob: 'what a shame' = 'F-'`
>
> since it will not
> care about the type annotation beyond “***it evaluates without raising***”,
> a type checker that encounters it will flag it, unless disabled with
> `#type: ignore` or `@no_type_check`.
>
> However, since Python won’t care what the “type” is, if the above
> snippet is at the global level or in a class, `__annotations__` will
> include `{'alice': 'well done', 'bob': 'what a shame'}`.
>
> These stored annotations might be used for other purposes, but with
> this PEP we explicitly recommend type hinting as the preferred use of
> annotations.

For example, running your snippet with `mypy` will produce the following error:

```
file.py:1: error: Invalid type comment or annotation  [valid-type]
```